# How do I move the search icon to the right side on the action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, layout-inflater

The search bar is supposed to be here:

[image]

And in run-time it goes here:

[image]

This is the code for my menu activity:

```
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:title="@string/Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        />

</menu>
```

And I'm inflating it on another activity like this:

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_bar,menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

I also tried changing the gravity programatically like this:

`searchView.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(Gravity.RIGHT));`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, especially if it contains the reason as why it's not behaving as I expected since I'd really like to understand what's happening.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

remove `android:layoutDirection="rtl"`

Comment: Didn't work, and inserting that was the answer to the same question in another thread.